# Flutter - Accessing the String value of the dropdown button from the another widget with Provider

Tags: flutter, dropdown

I would like to get the value of the dropdown from the other widget in the real estate app. Say I have two widgets. First one is the dropdown widget, and the second one is Add New Property widget (or a page).. I would like to access the value of the dropdown from the Add New Property.
I could achieve this with `final Function onChanged;` but Im wondering if there is another way to achieve with the Provider package or the `ValueNotifier`

the code below is my Dropdown button widget

```
class PropertyType extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onChanged;
  const PropertyType({
    super.key,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  @override
  State<PropertyType> createState() => _PropertyTypeState();
}

class _PropertyTypeState extends State<PropertyType> {
  final List<String> _propertyTypeList = propertyType;
  String? _propertyType = 'No Info';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ANPFormContainer(
      fieldTitle: 'Property Type',
      subTitle: 'အိမ်ခြံမြေအမျိုးအစား',
      child: FormBuilderDropdown<String>(
        name: 'a2-propertyType',
        initialValue: _propertyType,
        items: _propertyTypeList
            .map(
              (itemValue) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: itemValue,
                child: Text(itemValue),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            _propertyType = val;
            widget.onChanged(val);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the "Add New Property" form page

```
class ANPTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ANPTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<ANPTest> createState() => _ANPTestState();
}

class _ANPTestState extends State<ANPTest> {
  final TextEditingController _propertyid = TextEditingController();
  String _propertyType = 'No Info';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ZayyanColorTheme.zayyanGrey,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            PropertyID(propertyID: _propertyid),
            PropertyType(onChanged: (String value) {
              _propertyType = value;
            }),
            addVerticalSpacer(25),
            ANPNextButton(onPressed: _onpressed),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onpressed() {
    final anp = MdlFirestoreData(
            propertyid: _propertyid.text, propertyType: _propertyType)
        .toFirestore();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Selling Posts').add(anp);
  }
}
```

Thank you for helping me out.
Best

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could use `Getx` or `provider` package  by creating a controller(function) and the package helps you to have access to variables in
your controller to use them everywhere in your program,
you may need to learn about [`Getx`](https://pub.dev/packages/get)
it can help you manage your navigation and state